# Configuring keyboard layouts: 3-way switch, 3rd layout when CapsLock is on

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to configure my keyboard in this way:

I have 3 layouts, 2 of which I use fairly often (eng, rus) and 1 I use occasionally (e.g. when I'm writing some official letters) - cz. The difference between cz and eng keyboard layouts make it difficult to for example write code with this layout, and I use it rare enough to have it out of basic layouts cycle.

So the question is: can I somehow configure X to cycle through 2 layouts by-default[en/ru] and turn on cz layout when its needed by pressing CapsLock?

Thanks,